# how can i turn an goto label loop into for or while loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, goto, decompiler, deobfuscation

i want to understand a program that i think it's been obfuscated. it's so difficult to understand
i want turn goto-label loop into for or while loop.
i found some obfuscate program  but it's not working as i want
please help me!!!

```
private void calculatePageOffsets(ItemInfo paramItemInfo1, int paramInt, ItemInfo paramItemInfo2)
{
int m = this.mAdapter.getCount();
int i = getClientHeight();
float f2;
if (i > 0)
{
  f2 = this.mPageMargin / i;
  if (paramItemInfo2 == null)
    break label409;
  i = paramItemInfo2.position;
  if (i < paramItemInfo1.position)
  {
    j = 0;
    f1 = paramItemInfo2.offset + paramItemInfo2.heightFactor + f2;
    i += 1;
  }
}
else
{
  while (true)
  {
    if ((i > paramItemInfo1.position) || (j >= this.mItems.size()))
      break label409;
    for (paramItemInfo2 = (ItemInfo)this.mItems.get(j); ; paramItemInfo2 = (ItemInfo)this.mItems.get(j))
    {
      f3 = f1;
      k = i;
      if (i <= paramItemInfo2.position)
        break;
      f3 = f1;
      k = i;
      if (j >= this.mItems.size() - 1)
        break;
      j += 1;
    }
    f2 = 0.0F;
    break;
    while (k < paramItemInfo2.position)
    {
      f3 += this.mAdapter.getPageWidth(k) + f2;
      k += 1;
    }
    paramItemInfo2.offset = f3;
    f1 = f3 + (paramItemInfo2.heightFactor + f2);
    i = k + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried other decompilers?

Comment: This is all wrong.  The labeled `break` conditions look like `for` loop conditions that were not decompiled correctly, possibly due to control flow obfuscation or being passed through a tool like dex2jar.  You cannot trust this output; try a different decompiler.  CFR will apply topological sorting, which may yield better results.